# What is happening? Three different types for the same stuff in four lines of code?

Tags: c++, std

I borrowed this from another question about fragmentation, but I'm not bothered by that.  I'm more worried that I don't understand the function at all. in terms of types and data lifetimes :(

The same data is represented by a std::vector, (a dynamic aray type with internal metadata), a pointer to the string data therein, (return parameter), and the declared return type, which is a std:string.

QUESTIONS:
How does the data get safely out of the function when the std::vector is going to be destroyed?  Is it implicitly copied?  Is the dynamic array of char in the vector 'detached' from the vector and returned as a std::string type so that no bulk copy is required?  Sometimes, I think that C++ and the std library is trying to get me...

I've been using C++ for some while but stuff like this does my 'ed in.

```
std::string TestFragmentation()
{
    std::vector<char> buffer(500);
    SomeCApiFunction( &buffer[0], buffer.size() ); // Sets buffer to null-terminated string data
    return &buffer[0];
}
```

Comment: Looks like a single char is possibly implicitly converted to std::string to me. Did you post all the code?

Comment: This code looks freakin' Evil to me!

Comment: @0A0D, the `&` in front of `buffer[0]` means that it's using the pointer to the first char in `buffer`. So the `std::string` will copy everything in buffer until it first encounters a `\0`. If there were no `&`, then you'd be completely correct that it could only possibly see a single `char`.

Comment: @sblom: Ah, missed the `&`. Thanks

Comment: This is actually a routine combination of two common C++ patterns. One is used when code that uses vectors of characters has to interoperate with code that doesn't. You allocate a vector of the needed size and pass a pointer to the first byte and the size to another function. Often, you resize the vector on return. The other is used when you need to hold an object in existence while you compose a return value. It's commonly used with things like lock holders. For example: `scoped_lock f(lock); return j;` This makes a copy of `j` while the lock is held. Far from evil, this is all routine.

Comment: Why not just new() the vector and return a pointer to it?  Why try to drive me to drink with such shenanigans?

Comment: It's working anyway.  I've had enough single malt, so I've opened a bottle of 'The Famous Grouse', AKA 'I hate hidden copying of massive buffers'.

Comment: @MartinJames Typically because the code calling this requires a string. This is, unfortunately, all too common when code that uses a vector has to interoperate with code that uses a string. This code deals with three different representations, vector of character, pointer plus size, and string.

Comment: You are just as able to write zero-copy code in C++ as in C. However, you then have to start worrying about who "owns" the memory and what to do if you have other people using pointers to it and you can't move it safely. You dig yourself back into a C hole :)

Comment: @MartinJames C++11 move semantics (as well as new functionality such as emplace_back) practically eliminate unnecessary copies when used correctly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The data stored by a `std::vector` is guaranteed to be contiguous, so `&buffer[0]` gets you a raw pointer to the beginning of that data.<sup>1</sup>

And `std::string` has a constructor which takes a `const char *`, which copies the data.  That is being implicitly called in the return statement (the compiler is allowed to call at most one implicit conversion operation to avoid compile-time errors).

In both cases (the `vector` and the `string`), the memory for the corresponding backing buffer is managed by the container class, so there is no possibility of a memory leak or similar (so long as your raw C function creates a valid null-terminated C-style string and doesn't trample beyond the buffer bounds).

---

<sub>1. Note, however, that there are no guarantees that it will stay in one place.  As soon as you grow or shrink the vector, it's likely that it will be copied elsewhere in memory, invalidating all raw pointers that were pointing at it.  And if the `vector` itself is destructed, then of course the backing data is no longer valid.</sub>

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean

Comment: @trinithis: While this is good information, how is it related?

Comment: And, of course, the destructor for the vector isn't called until the vector goes out of scope. It must be in scope during the generation of the `return` value because it's *used* there.

Comment: So what about the part where we "return" a pointer to a stack variable that's about to go out of scope?  If we magically allocate a new string ... who ever deallocates it????

Comment: We don't return a pointer to a stack variable, we return a string. The return is by value, so it's deallocated when it goes out of scope, per normal C++ rules.

Comment: @0A0D: It's related because this question is concerns automatic promotion. `explicit` is what you would use to avoid this.

Comment: Sometimes, it seems like the whole std library is designed to perform as much data copying as possible whilst hiding it so that the developer never realises why performance is bad.  This is especially effective with classes like Concurrent.BlockingCollection - a templated class seemingly designed to enable developers to copy in and out massive buffers so that the queue can be kept locked as long as possible and contention maximized. Should raise an exception if anyone tries to copy in a type with more than 128 bytes.

Comment: @Paul, do you think it would still be as confusing if the function had ended with `return std::string(&buffer[0])`? Then it's clear that the pointer to the vector's data is being used to construct a string *before* returning. It also serves as a reminder that the return type is string, not char*, since that detail can sometimes get lost in the visual distance between a function's return-type declaration and the `return` statement.

Comment: It's more typing, but yes, actually I would prefer 'return std::string(&buffer[0])'.  I could see immediately 'Oh! there must be a ctor overload for C-style strings'.

Comment: A `return std::string(&buffer[0])` will cause another copying of the string unless the compiler optimizes it away.

Comment: @bjhend - Aaarrgghh!  Will no one rid me of this turbulent copying?

Comment: @bjhend: I would be very surprised if any mainstream compiler treated the two cases differently.

Comment: Implicit conversions are a PITA. It makes your eyes stop at that point (where the cute developer used implicit conversion) and think "WTF?".